# Popoto.js custom cypher query

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to use Popoto.js with custom cypher query? All Popoto.js examples are building the Popoto.js query automatically by clicking the graph nodes. I would like to know if it is possible to add first the query (in a text box) and afterwards to generate the graph based on the query.